# Select | HTML | Как избавиться от лагов?

Tags: php, html, laravel, form

Есть простой селект:

```
<select class="form-control" id="in-select-genres">
    <option selected disabled>Выбрать</option>
    @foreach(config('genres') as $genre)
        <option value="{{$genre}}" id="gn_{{$loop->iteration}}">{{$genre}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Он сделан специально для жанров, которых не более 30 шт. **НО**, есть другой селект, только для **ТЕГОВ**. Проблема в том, что тегов более **6.5к!!!**
Поэтому, перед каждым открытием селектора он тормозит. Может кто-то подсказать, как это исправить, помимо очевидного уменьшения кол-во тэгов.

Comment: suggest сделать -- пользователь набирает текст в инпут, идут запросы по ходу, ему подсказки

Comment: Попробуй не выводить все элементы, добавь поиск

Comment: Сделать Ajax подгрузку тегов

Comment: @Sergei Kirjanov, можно пример? Я никогда не слышал про такую технологию.

Comment: вот вам пример - [select2 ajax data](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax). Лучший вариант - показывать определённое кол-во изначально и использовать подгрузку при скролле

Comment: @InDevX, оформи это как ответ.